# arm_navigation compilation error on fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, arm-navigation, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated on the wiki page http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation, I installed the sources of the package using:
`hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/armnavigation/armnavigation -b default`

Unfortunately, the compilation fails because the package `mapping_rviz_plugin` does not find the file `rviz/properties/string_property.h`.

This file does not exit in the repository  `rviz/properties`. FYI, I installed `rviz` from the command `git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization.git -b visualization-1.8` as stated on the wiki http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz.

I tried to gather this header from different source on the web but it seems that the file `collision_map_display.cpp` needs more modifications.

Any hints to fix this ?
Is there a repository for stable sources ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66121/arm_navigation-compilation-error-on-fuerte/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default branch you've checked out is for Groovy, and the RViz API has changed between Fuerte and Groovy. Just check out the Fuerte branch:

```
roscd arm_navigation
hg checkout fuerte
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-07-01**:
Thenks. I did not notice that the repository was the same for both releases.